# OpenCV error due possibly to different "step"

Tags: c++, opencv

I have converted some code from old Opencv to the c++ version, and I get an error at matrix multiplication.

```
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 
'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), 
nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array')
```

On the web, this error seems to be associated with having different number of channels - mine are all 1.

What I did find different though is a **"step"** - on one it is 24, on another is 32.

Where is this step ?

I created both input matrices using

```
cv::Mat YYY(3, 4, CV_64FC1);   // step 32
cv::Mat XXX(3, 3, CV_64FC1);   // step 24
```

Yet they seem to have different step ?

Could this be the culprit for the error in `cv::multiply(XXX,YYY, DDD);`  ?

Is it not possible to perform operations (like a mask) between different types ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code that gives you the error? It's usually clearer than attempting to explain with words.

Comment: I just edited - I get error on the cv::multiply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::multiply()` performs *element-wise* multiplication of two matrices. As the error states, your matrices are not the same size.

You may be looking for matrix multiplication, which is accomplished via the `*` operator. Thus

```
cv::Mat DDD = XXX * YYY;
```

will compile and run correctly.

For the record, this has nothing (directly) to do with the `step` field, which for your matrices is the number of columns times `sizeof(double)`, since your matrices are of type `CV_64FC1`. Things get more complicated if the matrices are not continuous, but that is not the case for you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked great - I thought that cvMultiply would be replaced by cv::multiply... Seems that the c++ version is so much smarter ;-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If you haven't found it already, the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/index.html) is a good place to read up on the C++ API. Sometimes a quick search for a misbehaving function can get you exactly what you need!